# new iPad causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS on presentPopoverFromRect

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

My app crashes when presenting a Popover for an image picker, but only on the new iPad 3. I assume it has something to do with the new resolution.

My code to present the Popover:

```
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[selectPhotoButton frame] inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Works fine on iPad 1 and iPad 2, but o the "new iPad", I get the following crash/message:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x24)
```

Any idea what could cause this? My App Store rating is decreasing by the minute..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

- `popover` was deallocated but the pointer was not set to nil
- `selectPhotoButton` was deallocated but the pointer was not set to nil
- `self.view` was deallocated but the pointer was not set to nil